# Autofill with variable number of rows

Tags: vba, excel, autofill

I am trying to automate a monthly report in Excel with VBA where the final autofill is based on variable number of rows that change monthly with the change in # of clients. For example: if this month I have 25 clients, I could easily hardcode that I want to create 25 rows of my report. But in the next month when I have 30 clients, my code still would say 25 and therefore would miss five clients.

One solution I am trying to work on is to count the number of rows and apply that to the autofill formula. Trying to find code that would read like this: Autofill Range A1 to C "Number of rows in Worksheet X."

Now I know this clearly doesn't work, but this was my poor best attempt:

```
Sub FillReport()
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("D1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTA(A:A)"
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("A1:C1").Select
Selection.Autofill Destination:=Range("A1:C(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D1").Select)")
```

I didn't expect this work but wanted to try it anyway. As you can see I am quite the VBA novice...

If anyone has any insight that would be very helpful as I feel like there should be a way to accomplish this that I am just completely missing on my own.

Thanks.

Comment: You should specify the tools you are using (programming language) and what you have achieved so far.

Comment: IvanH: Sorry I missed that originally. I am using VBA. I have been able to completely automate the report that is sourced from 4 different spreadsheets but am completely stuck on this last piece which is only essentially a copy and paste function.

Comment: Without proper tags you are unlikely to get an answer. But some so far attempted code is still missing.

Comment: Thank you already for your help IvanH. Hopefully with your edits and the poor coding attempt I just included we can figure it out.

Comment: Will there be the right number of rows to begin with?

Comment: Enderland: when I do it manually with "Macro Recorder" it sets a hard autofill range (i.e. Range("A1:C20")). So the issue is when, next month when I theoretically have more clients, it will only autofill down to row 20 when I now have 25 clients. In actuallity, I am doing this when over 400 client names, I have just been using small numbers as examples.

Answer (score 0):

I like to do this using a range value I create manually to make it more clear.

So something like:

```
Dim myRngStr as string
myRngStr = "A1:D" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").end(xldown).row 'I don't know where you will find this actually
Range("A1").Autofill Destination:=Range(myRngStr)
```

Comment: I keep getting "Autofill method of Range class failed" message. Could you give me some instruction on how to input this into my sub and which items I have to change accordingly? I have never used "myRngStr" hence the probability I am not implementing your answer correctly.